# Need help in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

[My code](http://plnkr.co/edit/wHM5n1dhNBTY9PulqEBU?p=preview)

I want to repeat slides only in `sliderOne` for which I have added filter as below.

```
<div ng-repeat="slider in sliderData " >
    <div ng-repeat="slide in slider | filter : sliderData" >1</div>
</div>
```

I am not getting where I am going wrong. All slides are getting repeated.

Comment: I think your filter is wrong! sliderData is a Array and you are using this array in second base array filter. Check your filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this

```
<div ng-repeat="slider in sliderData[selectedSlider]" >
  {{slider}}
</div>
```

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/v6upuVdhouTqCwDcTLjj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat only in slider one. You can have an ng-repeat on it then.

Like

```
<div ng-repeat="slider in sliderData.sliderOne" >
    Hello {{slider}}
</div>
```

here is your updated plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/d2y0FGXbAaAm34NiTsXA?p=preview

Comment: I need to change content when I select option from select field.

Comment: @will.kelly tell me where in the question did u mention that ?